# Can't start django project in docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, redis, celery

At startup Redis does not work, therefore caching does not work, as I realized there is no connection to the database. I can't make loaddata fixtures and Celery can't connect to Redis either. In general, nothing works.  No matter how many examples I found on how to create these files, everywhere it is done like this.

1. Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD python manage.py migrate \
    && python manage.py loaddata site_blog/fixtures/posts.json \
    && python manage.py loaddata site_blog/fixtures/post_category.json \
    && python manage.py loaddata site_blog/fixtures/comments.json \
    && python manage.py loaddata users/fixtures/users.json \
    && python manage.py makemigrations \
    && python manage.py migrate \
    && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

2. docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres-db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: db_mp_blog_username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: db_mp_blog_password
      POSTGRES_DB: db_mp_blog
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  site:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
      - redis
    environment:
      DB_NAME: "db_mp_blog"
      DB_USER: "db_mp_blog_username"
      DB_PASSWORD: "db_mp_blog_password"
      DB_HOST: "postgres-db"
      DB_PORT: 5432
      CELERY_BROKER_URL: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
      CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
      SECRET_KEY: 'django-insecure-c467_p2n3g4ni%yq_ebaqe1j2=!ozmn=zvgh8i23uzos&9p3pc'
    restart: always

  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A blog worker --loglevel=info
    depends_on:
      - site
      - redis
      - postgres-db
    environment:
      DB_NAME: "db_mp_blog"
      DB_USER: "db_mp_blog_username"
      DB_PASSWORD: "db_mp_blog_password"
      DB_HOST: "postgres-db"
      DB_PORT: 5432
      CELERY_BROKER_URL: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
      CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
      SECRET_KEY: 'django-insecure-c467_p2n3g4ni%yq_ebaqe1j2=!ozmn=zvgh8i23uzos&9p3pc'
```

Comment: Where you set for example `CELERY_BROKER_URL` to `127.0.0.1`, you're trying to tell the Django container to connect to itself for Redis, not the other container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a network in your Docker Compose file and add all of your services to that network. Then, modify the addresses in your Docker Compose according to the service. For example, change

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
```

to

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL: 'redis://redis:6379'
```